# PHP validating and filtering a list of international numbers so im left only with valid cellphone numbers from that country

Tags: php, regex, validation, filtering

I am building a tool that will validate and filter a list of numbers from csv/xlsx.

1. filter all non cellular.
2. validate that its indeed a cellular number from a chosen country (maybe dynamicaly).

tried google's libphonenumber but i realy didnt understand how to implement it.
please help with a basic regex so i can modify it with different country codes.

Comment: show some code what you tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

That problem is REALLY complex, and it is not always resolvable.

For example, while most (all?) European countries have separate prefixes for mobile numbers, that's not true in the NANPA region (US, Canada and others). Indeed, landlines and mobile numbers share the same geographical prefix, and there's absolutely no way to distinguish them.

Google's `libphonenumber` is actually great, and it contains the data for each country. For most countries it also includes methods to distinguish between mobile numbers and landlines, *when it's possible* (for NANPA, it always returns the "landline or mobile" constant). I've used that library for many projects, and it's really good (I've also contributed to it).
However, `libphonenumber` is officially available only for C/C++, Java and JavaScript, so you can't really execute it with PHP code. There's an [UNOFFICIAL PHP port available](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php), which seems also pretty updated, but I do not know how well it works. Docs and examples are available there too.
(Eventually, however, the biggest value in `libphonenumber` is in the data tables, the rest is just "companion code").

Answer (score -1):

Well first of all you have to know all the number formats.....You could possibly use `preg_match`to  find like + in front of the number or () etc. Then I would explode first two numbers which most likely would be country code numbers.....then just do if statements that would look at these two numbers and based on what these numbers are decide what country is the number from.

Comment: ok, im a noob - is that a legit method of writing a program? i mean entering all countries codes and making million 'if' statemnets?

Comment: That's a legitimate method of writing an app, and basically it's what libphonenumber does (even though they don't use millions of if's :) ). However, libphonenumber has been in development for many years (and it's backed by Google!), so their data tables are MUCH more complete than any one you could possibly write yourself.

Comment: -1 This is way too naive. Country codes are not necessarily exactly two numbers (there are more than 100 countries in the world) and the rest is hand-waving.

Comment: This is just a exaple how such thing could be possibly achived....but it is up to the programmer to do its homework, how many countries there are in the world, all the possible country code numbers etc.......